# How to use future forecasted weather data as input in LSTM model

Tags: concatenation, lstm, layer

I am working on making a water demand forecasting model that takes into account time and meteorological conditions. Ideally it would take into account the previous years water demand+meteorological conditions+time, and then use current time and meteorological conditions and **also it would take next 14 days weather forecasted data as input.**
So here I need help hot to start modelling for 2 different time horizon input using LSTM. I have some structure for implementation but I don't have idea about how it will work.So help me to understand this and give me other solution approach also.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyzQU.png)

Expecting to get prediction of next 14 days water demand using past 7 days water consumption data and meteorological conditions data of last 7 days and next 14 days forecasted data as input.